Conflicting advice from WhatsApp faq re video calling. Which is correct?
This WhatsApp FAQ page implies that I can make a video call using WhatsApp Web ("To make or receive video calls on WhatsApp..."), while this WhatsApp FAQ page implies that I cannot make a video call using WhatsApp Web ("You can’t make or receive video calls from WhatsApp Web.")
Unless I have misunderstood the advice, they cannot both be correct - either you can or you cannot. Which one of the two is correct?

You cannot make video calls using WhatsApp Web.
The second step in the instructions you linked, "Click the Video call icon", will redirect you to WhatsApp Desktop.
While the information on the web tab "How to make a video call" does imply that it is supported, it is not.
